# error TS7027: Unreachable code detected typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

```
  sortArrayDate(arrayToSort, arrayDateKey, ascendingOrDecending) {
    if (true) {
      arrayToSort.sort(function(a, b){
        if (a[arrayDateKey] === '' || a[arrayDateKey] === null) {
          return 1;
        }
        if (b[arrayDateKey] === '' || b[arrayDateKey] === null) {
          return -1;
        }
        return new Date(a[arrayDateKey]).getTime() - new Date(b[arrayDateKey]).getTime();
   });
    } else {
        arrayToSort.sort(function(a, b){  //getting error
        if (a[arrayDateKey] === '' || a[arrayDateKey] === null) {
          return 1;
        }
        if (b[arrayDateKey] === '' || b[arrayDateKey] === null) {
           return -1;
        }
        return new Date(b[arrayDateKey]).getTime() - new Date(a[arrayDateKey]).getTime();
      });
    }
  }
```

I am getting the above error on the mentioned line.Whats the issue with the code. I am trying to sort dates from an array.

Comment: @Nancy, I supouse you want write if(ascendingOrDecending) not if(true)

Answer (score 11):

You have if condition on second line of function as:

```
if(true)
```

And then you have else part as well. Since first if will always be true, else can never be reached/called. That is why typescript is giving the unreachable code error.

If you want the code inside if to always execute, you can bring it out of `if/else` condition.

In order to disable this error without changing the code (not recommended), you can change the compiler config using `tsconfig.json`. Add this to disbale this warning:

```
"allowUnreachableCode": true
```

Comment: That's a good tip. I know there is no sense on leaving unreachable code, but sometimes, we just add a `if(true)` or force a `return` in the middle of the code to perform some quick tests of specific validations. So this can be handy to avoid all your code to be automatically deleted by the "autofix on save".

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is right, since you use `if(true)` any statements on the `else` branch is unreachable. You can disable this (although I don't recoamnd it) using `"allowUnreachableCode": true`

Answer (score 0):

Your `if(true)` says that you always go into that if condition. Therefore the `else` part cannot be reached, because your if is always `true`

Answer (score 0):

The typescript compiler is giving unreachable code error as the else part cannot be reached/called. Instead of changing anything in the compiler config (`tsconfig.json`), I would recommend fooling the compiler with a condition that would always result in boolean `true`.

For example replacing `if(true)` with `if(Math.random())`.

The return type of `Math.random()` is `number` making the compiler think that it can result in any number, including `zero` which might result in a boolean `false`, but actually `Math.random()` will never give a `zero` and always a positive number resulting in a boolean `true` every time.

Here is the complete code :

```
  sortArrayDate(arrayToSort, arrayDateKey, ascendingOrDecending) {
    if(Math.random()) {
      arrayToSort.sort(function(a, b){
        if (a[arrayDateKey] === '' || a[arrayDateKey] === null) {
          return 1;
        }
        if (b[arrayDateKey] === '' || b[arrayDateKey] === null) {
          return -1;
        }
        return new Date(a[arrayDateKey]).getTime() - new Date(b[arrayDateKey]).getTime();
   });
    } else {
        arrayToSort.sort(function(a, b){  //no more error
        if (a[arrayDateKey] === '' || a[arrayDateKey] === null) {
          return 1;
        }
        if (b[arrayDateKey] === '' || b[arrayDateKey] === null) {
           return -1;
        }
        return new Date(b[arrayDateKey]).getTime() - new Date(a[arrayDateKey]).getTime();
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: `Math.random()` _can_ return exactly zero, although it’s just as unlikely as any other specific number. What it can never return is exactly one.

Answer (score 0):

The `else` part will only be active when your `if` condition is evaluated to false. So if you have something like `if(myVariable != null)` then you would reach the `else` block when your element `myVariable` is `null`, otherwise the `if` block is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Got this error resolved in react when the file renamed from .ts to .tsx.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).